# ASMX: Setting User/Password at run-time

Tags: c#, web-services, asmx, defaultnetworkcredentials

When I want to connect to my web service If I write it like this:

```
m_TransferServiceSoap.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
```

it is working. but I need a Login Form. so users can enter their user/pass

so I am creating a NetworkCredential instance and setting its user/pass members from what I get from that login form and then instead of using the line above I am writing this one:

```
m_TransferServiceSoap.Credentials = userpass; // the instance above.
```

but in this way when I call a method of that webService, it gives me errors .

Is it the wrong way to set credentials?

Comment: Are you including the domain name when you create your NetworkCredential?

Comment: no I am not... just I am setting the user and pass that I am getting from the text boxes on that Login form.
Hmm.. Ok .. so if I have something like this : "WHQ_A_DOMAIN\userID" ... then the first part should be passed as Domain and the second part should be passed as UserName?

Comment: Yes, the call should look something like this: var nc = new NetworkCredential( "Name","Password","Domain Name");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you including the domain name when you create your NetworkCredential?

the call should look something like this:

```
var nc = new NetworkCredential( "Name","Password","Domain Name");
```

***I've added this as an answer so that, if it worked, I can can the points...***

Patrick.

Comment: one more question about that:
right now my domain name has some pattern like this, which is set by the company "WHQ_A_DOMAIN\myUser" .
but I am not sure How it will look like when our clients are using it on their own domains?
so is there a way I can get the "Domain" name ? something that for example in my case would return "WHQ_A_DOMAIN"

Comment: Ok, looks like Environment.UserDomainName returns the domain name.
so always the pattern is like this: DOMAIN\userName

Answer (score 0):

this is what worked for me

```
myservice g = new myservice();
g.AuthenticationHeaderValue = new AuthenticationHeader();
//Authentication values
g.AuthenticationHeaderValue.UserName = "sdaaad";
g.AuthenticationHeaderValue.Password = "sbvbfb#%$3df";
```