# Set login credential for webservice

Tags: c#, web-services

I have made a simple web service in c#. I want to set credentials. 
how can i set??

Answer (score 3):

If Windows Credentials are required look at [asmx-setting-user-password-at-run-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3016739/asmx-setting-user-password-at-run-time)

If you require custom username/password delivery look at adding a SOAP Header [Create and Consume Web Services at Server and Client](http://www.asp101.com/articles/colin/webservices/default.asp) (Bottom of Article)